# How to create an Android TV emulator without touchscreen controls

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm porting my game to Android TV and would like to test with a virtual device that has no touchscreen. When using one of the provided Android TV device definition, it creates a TV but I can navigate in the Android Interface (and in my game) using touch controls (with the mouse).

`getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN)` returns `false`, but I don't get why I can manipulate with the mouse.

How can I totally disable touchscreen on an Android TV emulator?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Even without touch-screen capabilities, Android tries to emulate touch when a mouse, D-pad, or other pointing hardware is available. That's probably why you can interact with your touch controls using the mouse. You can test whether this is happening you can query for [`FEATURE_FAKETOUCH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_FAKETOUCH) (as with `getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FAKETOUCH)`).

If you really want to test your app on a device that has no pointing hardware at all (so touch can't even be faked), perhaps you can define an AVD using a Wear hardware profile. Otherwise, you may have some luck defining your own hardware profile.